# Transform the json according to below requirement in my project

Tags: javascript, json

```js
class Transformation {
  constructor() {
    this.colHeaders = {
      error_description: "Description",
      error_status: "Status",
      error_code: "Error Code"
    };
  }

  getColHeader() {
    return this.colHeaders;
  }
}

var jsonData = {
  error_description: "Already Rejected",
  error_status: "Faliure",
  error_code: "401"
};
var clmDetails = new Transformation();
var obj = clmDetails.getColHeader();
var json_conversion = {};
for (var key in jsonData) {
  if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var k = obj[key.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_")];
    var val = jsonData[key];
    json_conversion[k] = val;
  }
}

console.log(json_conversion);
```

```
    Input Json:
{
  "error_description": "Already Rejected",
  "error_status": "Faliure",
  "error_code": "401"
}


output Json I am getting:
O/P:
{
  "Description": "Already Rejected",
  "Status": "Faliure",
  "Error Code": "401"
}
```

But again I need to transform it to old json based on the output json that i am getting,for which I have to match the key of the output json with the value in class Transformation and then reform the old json like below.

```
Expected Output:
 {
      "error_description": "Already Rejected",
      "error_status": "Faliure",
      "error_code": "401"
 }
```

Below I have given the code above for  transformation  input to output json.
But I need again output json to input json as explained above.

I have to do it in the same Tranformation class,Need help.
Thanks in Advance.

Scenario:
Rest Service >>> JSON

```
{
      error_description: "Already Rejected",
      error_status: "Faliure",
      error_code: "401"
    }
```

> > transforming json(because I cant show the field name as error_description,It should be Description) and showing as form in ui as editable fields 
> >     again editing data and sending the  json to rest service

```
{
  "Description": "Already Rejected",
  "Status": "Faliure",
  "Error Code": "401"
}
```

But now json has been transformed so rest service wont take.So I need again the json as

```
{
      error_description: "Already Rejected",
      error_status: "Faliure",
      error_code: "401"
    }
```

And I cant add json transformation properties in Rest service as it is coming from 3rd party.

Comment: Your question is confusing, because the expected output matches the input `jsonData`. So doing nothing but assigning it to the output would satisfy your request.

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com).

Comment: And this is not JSON. This is a javascript object literal. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: i have given just a dummy json,actual json is large and dynamic and all the columns are not there in json.I have to retransform the json to input json as you said,I actually need it,i cant take the input json

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your question is unclear at the moment

Comment: edited the question please go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Transformation {
  constructor() {
    this.colOutHeaders = {
      error_description: "Description",
      error_status: "Status",
      error_code: "Error Code"
    };

    this.colInHeaders = {
      "Description": "error_description",
      "Status": "error_status",
      "Error Code": "error_code"
    };
  }

  getOutHeader() {
    return this.colOutHeaders;
  }

  getInHeader() {
    return this.colInHeaders;
  }
}

function transform(jsonData, obj) {

  var json_conversion = {};
  for (var key in jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var k = obj[key];
      var val = jsonData[key];
      json_conversion[k] = val;
    }
  }
  
  return json_conversion;
}

var jsonData = {
  error_description: "Already Rejected",
  error_status: "Faliure",
  error_code: "401"
};

var clmDetails = new Transformation();
var obj = clmDetails.getOutHeader();

output = transform(jsonData, obj);
console.log(output);

revertOutput = transform(output, clmDetails.getInHeader());
console.log(revertOutput);
```

I updated please try may be it helpful

Comment: But I cant add the same error_description: "error_description",
      error_status: "error_status",
      error_code: "error_code" as column headers because then 1st transformation will fail

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to do

Comment: edited the question and the scenario Please look into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot,It will do the job.Actually requirement is valid but to represent it in a question i find it difficult.Thanks for the solution